# how to set array of data through a loop to get access in a component using react?

Tags: reactjs

I  have a Problem Like this. I have made a component and create a componentDidMount method to access some data.

This is my component.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Grid, Message,Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import BodyBackgroundColor from 'react-body-backgroundcolor';

import web3 from '../ethereum/web3';
import trafficfine from '../ethereum/trafficfine';

import Layout from './Layout';
import Header from './Header';


export default class Officerreg extends Component {
  state ={
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
    officer: 0,
    officers:[]
  };

  async componentDidMount(){
    const officerCount = await trafficfine.methods.getofficerCount().call();
    for(let i=0;i<officerCount;i++){
      var officer={
        firstname:'',
        lastname:'',
        address:0
      }

      const officers = await trafficfine.methods.getNthOfficerName(i).call();
      officer.firstname=officers[0];
      officer.lastname=officers[1];
      officer.address=officers[2];
      this.setState({officers:officer});
    }

    console.log(this.state.officers);
  }

  onSubmit = async (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loading: true, errorMessage: ''});

    try{
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

      await trafficfine.methods.addOfficer(this.state.firstname,this.state.lastname,this.state.officer)
        .send({
          from: accounts[0]
        });

    }catch(err){
      this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message})
    }

    this.setState({ loading: false});
  }
    render(){
        return(
          <BodyBackgroundColor backgroundColor='#e9ebee'>
          <div >
          <Header></Header>
          <Layout style={{paddingTop:'100px'}}>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.Row>
              <Grid.Column width={10}>
                <Card style={{paddingTop:'40px',paddingBottom:'40px',paddingLeft:'50px',paddingRight:'50px',width:'2000px',marginTop:'40px',boxShadow: '0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)'}}>
                    <h2>Officers</h2>
                </Card>
              </Grid.Column>
              <Grid.Column width={6}>
            <Card style={{paddingTop:'40px',paddingBottom:'40px',paddingLeft:'50px',paddingRight:'50px',width:'1500px',marginTop:'40px',boxShadow: '0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)'}}>
           <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} error={!!this.state.errorMessage}>
             <center><h3>Add Officer</h3></center>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input placeholder='Sunil'  value={this.state.firstname}
                        onChange ={event => this.setState({ firstname: event.target.value})} />
              </Form.Field>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input placeholder='Bandara'  value={this.state.lastname}
                        onChange ={event => this.setState({ lastname: event.target.value})}/>
              </Form.Field>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>Address Of the officer</label>
                <input placeholder='Car'  value={this.state.officer}
                        onChange ={event => this.setState({ officer: event.target.value})}/>
              </Form.Field>
              <Message error header="Oops!" content={this.state.errorMessage} />
                    <Button loading={this.state.loading} color="green" basic>Add Officer</Button> <Button  loading={this.state.loading} color="red" basic >Clear</Button>
            </Form>
            </Card>
            </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>
            </Layout>

            </div>
            </BodyBackgroundColor>

        )
    }
}
```

Through the for loop, I am accessing a set of data. I want to access all of these data. So, how can I modify my ComponentDidMount method in order to make those all data to access in the component? What I have tried is not do what I expected. It just consoles log only the last officer. What I want is to access all officers.Can someone help me to find a solution for my Problem? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never do setState in loop in react instead do it outside the loop. Declare a local array variable outside for loop and push all the objects constructed to the array. Finally outside forloop do the setSTate to `officers` state

Since you are looping in `componentDidMount` I would recommend you to do as like below

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const officerCount = await trafficfine.methods.getofficerCount().call();
    const array = [];
    for(let i=0;i<officerCount;i++){
      const officer={
        firstname:'',
        lastname:'',
        address:0
      }

      const officers = await trafficfine.methods.getNthOfficerName(i).call();
      officer.firstname=officers[0];
      officer.lastname=officers[1];
      officer.address=officers[2];
      array.push(officer);
    }
    this.setState({officers:array});

  }
```

Please not whenever you do setState the modified state value won't be available immediately untill and unless your component renders. So to check updated state value do the console log of state in render like

```
 render(){
    console.log(this.state.officers);//you will get updated values here
    return(

    )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
this.setState(({ officers }) => ({
     officers: [ ...officers, officer
}));
```